# How to make frame automatically resize with window?

Tags: java, windows

When I resize the window, the scroll frame doesnt resize with it and just goes out of frame.
Is there any way to fix this? Here's a snippet of the code:

```
    TextEditor(){
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Emu Editor J");
        this.setSize(700,550);
        this.setResizable(true);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Cascadia Code",Font.PLAIN,20));
        
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.getWidth()-25,this.getHeight()-100));
       // scrollPane.setSize(this.getWidth()-25,this.getHeight()-100);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

I tried allowing resizable and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try using `BorderLayout` and add the panel to it with `BorderLayout.CENTER`.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused on how to do this - I'm a beginner with java

Comment: This is a good start: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/